# Executing calling class' method

Tags: php, oop

```
class Car
{
    $gas= new Gas();
    $gas->fill( 'filledHandler' );

    function filledHandler()
    {
        echo 'Gas has been filled!';
    }
}

class Gas
{
    function fill( $function )
    {
        // do something here
        $function(); 
    }
}
```

I need to call $function of calling class. Right now, it's looking for a global function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass the calling instance.

```
class Car
{
    function fillGas()
    {
        $gas = new Gas();
        $gas->fill($this, 'filledHandler');
    }

    function filledHandler()
    {
        echo 'Gas has been filled!';
    }
}

class Gas
{
    function fill($obj, $function)
    {
        // If you need the class name, use get_class($obj)
        $obj->$function();
    }
}
```

Comment: Grrrr.... I wasted half an hour on this thing, looking for ways to find which class is calling the method. I was looking in all the wrong places. Thank you BC!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Car
{
    function __construct()
    {
      $gas= new Gas();
      $gas->fill($this, 'filledHandler' );
    }

    function filledHandler()
    {
        echo 'Gas has been filled!';
    }
}

class Gas
{
    function fill($object, $function )
    {
        $object->$function();
    }
}
```

(Ask more question (like what exactly do you want to happen anyway) and get more answer text ^^.)